# JavaScript unexpected undefined value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, comparison

I am running the following JavaScript code:

```
// Return true if the given username and password are in the database,
// false otherwise.
function validCredentials(enteredUsername, enteredPassword) {
   
   // Database of usernames and passwords
   let usernames = ["smith",  "tron",      "ace",      "ladyj",    "anon"];
   let passwords = ["qwerty", "EndOfLine", "year1942", "ladyj123", "PASSWORD"];
   
   // Search the usernames array for enteredUsername 
   
   // Only return true if the enteredUsername is in username, and the
   // same location in passwords is enteredPassword
   if (usernames.includes(enteredUsername)){
      var correctPassword = passwords[usernames.indexOf(enteredUsername)];
      if(enteredPassword == correctPassword){
         return true;
         }    
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }  
}


console.log("Login for ladyj: " + validCredentials("ladyj", "ladyj123"));  // true
console.log("Login for ace: " + validCredentials("ace", "wrong"));  // false
console.log("Login for jake: " + validCredentials("jake", "???"));  // false
```

I am expecting console.log("Login for ace: " + validCredentials("ace", "wrong")); return false, but it returned undefined. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: `if(enteredPassword == correctPassword) { return true; }` does not have a corresponding `else` that returns false

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: You should let your IDE format the code for you, then it becomes obvious the ifs do not happen where / when you expect them to.

Answer (score 1):

You don't return in all possible branches (namely, if the username exists, but the password is incorrect). Move the `return false` outside the `else` to be the final statement in the function.

Alternatively, you could simplify the chain of `if` and `else` into one statement:

```js
return usernames.includes(enteredUsername) && 
       passwords[usernames.indexOf(enteredUsername)] === enteredPassword;
```

Comment: This answer guides one in the right direction.